# Any way to make segue.destinationViewController as? to judge one of UIViewControllers

Tags: swift

My code currently is like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let des = segue.destinationViewController as? AURReportViewController {
            des.currentType = currentType
        }

        if let des = segue.destinationViewController as? AURAddBeanViewController {
            des.currentType = currentType
        }
    }
```

Is there anyway to make make `as?` in one of `UIViewController`s at the same time?

```
if let des = segue.destinationViewController as? (AURReportViewController || AURAddBeanViewController) {
            des.currentType = currentType
        }
```

Comment: You can create a protocol with that property and make your view controllers conform to that protocol. Or the same with a subclass of UIViewController (won't work if you want a subclass of a UITableVC and a UICollectionVC, for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't. These two types don't inherit from one another. Swift is strongly typed. In your proposal, inside the `if let`, `des` can one of two different types. The compiler isn't set up to handle this situation of "in this block this variable might be AURAddBeanViewController or it might be AURReportViewController (or it might be a ... etc)". The compiler wants to known exactly what type each variable is.

Now if each class conformed to a shared protocol `HasCurrentType`, the compiler could be expected to understand "in this block, this variable conforms to HasCurrentType". Type safety rules are honored and the compiler is happy.

Apple documents [protocol conformance testing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html) in the section "Checking for Protocol Conformance", with a sample called `HasArea`. So in your case, `if let des = segue.destinationViewController as? HasCurrentType` ...

Comment: Thank you, Graham. I understood. But if i make both view controllers conform to ```HasCurrentType```, how to change this part: if let des = segue.destinationViewController as? (AURAddBeanViewController || AURReportViewController) of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Nil Coalescing Operator. Is this one working ?

```
 if let des = segue.destinationViewController as? AURReportViewController ?? segue.destinationViewController as? AURAddBeanViewController {
        des.currentType = currentType
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, it works for the condition. But with an error.  The inheritance is :```AURAddBeanViewController < Base2ViewController <  Base1ViewController``` and ```AURReportViewController < Base1ViewController``.  ```Base2ViewController``` and ```AURReportViewController ``` both have a property: ```currentType```. In this way in your answer the error is:
Value of type '```Base1ViewController```' has no member 'currentType'

Comment: yeah first it try to find destinationViewController as AURReportViewController, Then if it failed goes to the other option. That's how it works. :) But EmilioPelaez suggestion is also good one.  Hope that my answer will help

Comment: If as? AURReportViewController failed, should goes as? AURAddBeanViewController, but AURAddBeanViewController inherit the property ```currentType``` from Base2ViewController, why it with the error?

Comment: This error shows when failed the first statement not the second statement, try  to swap both statement and click the same button. Then you can find out. Because first one is not the destination view controller, That's why it shows this error. But second condition is valid and it will not show any errors.

Comment: Sorry Silva, if goes in AURReportViewController should has currentType inherit from Base2ViewController too. Why still has no member 'currentType'?

Comment: I have no idea about that :( . Hope that my answer will help you to figure it out your problem :)